# Set focus dynamically created textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm adding an input field dynamically :

```
var dy = $('<textarea />',{class: 'tf', placeholder: 'Type Here', type: 'textarea', id: 'dyid_'+i })

dy.prependTo($('#inputs'));
```

and after doing so, I want the input field to have focus with blinking text cursor. How do I do this?

I've tried this but does not work.

```
$('#dyid_'+i).focus();
```

Comment: The problem is with your focus selector. Where the var i came from? Is it this code inside for loop? Without that, it should work. See fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/3jd2e0t5/

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: You've red it wrong. I'm creating multiple DIVs so the ID is increasing. I've used `i` for illustrative purposes hoping that's understandable to a person answering.

Comment: If it is in the same code block, you already have the JQuery object in `dy`, so you could just do `dy.focus()`

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez: I see your point but dosen't work. I also tried `dy.prependTo($('body')).focus();`. Did not work.

Comment: @Fergoso Those fiddle just for illustrate that the problem is in your i variable. It could be better if you can post full code related to this.

Answer (score 0):

By just looking at the code you provided, I assume it takes place in a loop? Be sure to enclose it in a closure to capture the index properly, otherwise they will all be the same.

Could you create a js fiddle with some more code, to get in which context it's executed?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, check the `i` value, this might be the culprit

```js
var dy = $('<textarea />',{class: 'tf', placeholder: 'Type Here', type: 'textarea', id: 'dyid_1' })

dy.prependTo($('body')).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on Firefox. Could be the Stack Snippet behavior?

Comment: strange, i just tried that in Firefox and it works fine as well (what version are you using ?) @GuillermoGutiérrez

Comment: I have Firefox 36.0.1 on Windows 7. However, I tried it on Chrome 41.0.2272.89 m and it works perfectly.